# I want to rearrange divs on a WordPress theme. How can I find out what PHP page to edit?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm using the Bimber theme; this is the page I want to rearrange in many ways: https://bimber.bringthepixel.com/relink/25-delicious-things-to-cook-in-september/#comments-section

**If I wanted to, for instance, bring the Votes box element (under "what do you think?") way up and place it where the "209 Shares" element is, how would I even start doing that?**

***My attempt:*** I've got the "Sublime Text" program and I can open the entire Theme folder and do a "Find in files..." search for the Class name of that vote box. Then try to see what .php file mentions that vote box name.

The class of the Votes box element, when I inspect it with Chrome Dev Tools, appears to be "snax-voting-container-body". So I search for that, but no PHP files show up in the results. Only CSS files, and a ton of them (like over 20). So i don't know where to begin... How do I do this process of rearranging elements of a Wordpress theme page made mostly of PHP files?

Comment: Can you please add a piece of reproducable code to your post ?

Comment: Try searching in plugins folder instead.

Comment: @SteveNosse I genuinely don't understand how to do that, for my question, since I don't know how to locate the PHP code for the page I'm interested in modifying.

Comment: The votes box element need not necessarily be in a php file. I speculate that it may have been generated by a javascript script, maybe from a plugin. If so, you may have to modify the plugin.  A quick google turned up this as a likely candidate https://codecanyon.net/item/snax-viral-frontend-uploader/16540363?rel=bringthepixel

Comment: Maybe have a look at what the plugin offers by way of customizing placement of voting boxes.